# How to wait till ScrollViewer.ScrollToTop(); is finished?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my little application, I need to work with a TextBlock visual, but before I do that, I need to forcibly scroll to the top of the TextBlock content (TextBlock is enclosed in ScrollViewer]. So I call method

```
ScrollViewer1.ScrollToTop();
```

and program continues rendering TextBlock visual to a RenderTargetBitmap, but bitmap top part is not visible because of unfinished ScrollToTop(). If I scroll to top manually and then push button to proceed working with TextBlock visual, resulting bitmap is correct, but I want the program to continue automatically.
I could maybe implement a 1 or 2 seconds "pause" in background thread, but this is not how I would want to solve the issue. I need some notification, that the forced scrolling to the top was finished.
Any suggestions, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you manage the scrolling yourself, with a `Thread.Sleep()` while loop, decrementing the Y scroll?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be listing to `ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged Event`

and checking `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset Property`

when it is VerticalOffset appropriate range start execution of your code.